# Man floating on a red ocean possibly involves time travel

Tags: story-identification

This novel was probably written in the 1960's or 70's.

I recall the book cover had a man floating possibly in a raft on a red ocean and that it may involve time travel.

It also may have been the first book in a series.

Possibly about alternate futures the main character was more like an anthropologist( or archaeologist). The main character name possibly started with a "Q" (but its not "Q" from star trek) and may have been religious possibly Christian?

The main character ends up in an asylum.

I believe it was on Earth. Don't believe space travel was involved but on the book cover he may have been wearing a space suit.

Read the book back in the 90's and would like to re-read apologies for the vagueness.

---

Its not

- "The Godhead Trilogy" - James Morrow. Which has the two-mile-long corpse of God found floating at sea
- "Out of the Silent Planet" or its sequel "Perelandra" - C. S. Lewis
- "Interstellar Pig" -  William Sleator. Which mentions "At sea, the Captain rescued a man floating in the ocean..."
- "Raft" - Stephen Baxter
- ''Worlds Apart (The Outer Limits)''

The following image is similar to what I remember on book cover (apart from the missing man of course)

[image: example red sunset]

Comment: That's a bit vague. Remember anything else about the plot or characters?

Comment: Do you remember if there was any space travel involved? Were the events on Earth?

Comment: @amaretto Reminded me of that a bit as well. *Perelandra* is the sequel to *Out of the Silent Planet*. Those books had a bit of a religious bent, as well.

Comment: @amaretto I don't believe he was wearing a helmet. And in my vague recollection I feel that he didn't require the suit in the book.

Comment: This reminds me of an outer limits episode where an astronaught ends on an alien world but can't get home because the worm hole he went through introduced a time distortion. I'll find the episode out and see if it was based on a book

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worlds_Apart_(The_Outer_Limits)

Comment: @ATB Looks to have been written by Chris Dickie. I don't believe this is it :( Thanks

Comment: This is not the book you were looking for, but you might also like [The Last Day on Mars](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25183019-last-day-on-mars), which incidentally also has time travel and a similar cover!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be *Seeking the Mythical Future,* which was written by Trevor Hoyle and published in 1977? Chris Queghan, an anthropologist, appears to travel in a space suit through the event horizon of a black hole into an alternate universe, and lands in a blood-red sea on Earth IVn.

I haven’t read it myself, but there are more details, which may contain spoilers, at [Trevor Hoyle’s Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trevor_Hoyle) and most of the details seem to match.

The cover:

[image]

Comment: @amaretto Added it in.

Comment: @Mithrandir On my phone I get automatically redirected to the mobile version when I visit the normal version. So your change doesn't help mobile users, but is annoying for desktop users.

Comment: Thanks for the cover art! I wrote my answer on my iPad, with one of my cats insistently sleeping on my hand. I saw the cover, but typing was hard enough and then the claws slowly came out. It was clear that my hand had to stop moving. Immediately.

Comment: @rosesunhill That's it, Thank you very much

Comment: That's impressive, I rather doubted this one would get identified!

Comment: @OrganicMarble That was my belief also rusesunhill did well :)